# jQueryUI Tabs and jqGrid trouble with initialization

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, tabs, rotation, head

My use of jqGrid is inserted in Tabs navigation, as below :

[image]

where first row is for main tabs, second row for subtabs of each main tabs and third row for opttabs for each subtab.
Each page in panel is an independent script with jqGrid.

The trouble is for a script which do rotate of header columns at initialization :

[image]

If this script is the first I launch after browser is open, all is fine.
But every time I run this script after other tabs have been clicked, some tasks are not executed, such these, rotate is not executed and width not shrink to browser width : 
[image][image]

Many thanks for driving me about this problem, anyway to solve it.
Have a nice day
Jihel

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute the script (the function) which rotate the column headers at the first activation of the tab. At the moment the grid will be *visible* and all should work fine. I suppose that you have problem with rotating of column headers of *hidden* grids. You can use `activate` callback or `"tabsactivate"` event handler if you use new version oj jQuery UI or use `select` callback or `"tabsselect"` event handler if you use old version of jQuery UI.